# Why is pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5 failing?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

I build it like this:

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

But it fails. Below is the failure. How can I get this image to build successfully?
I swear this was working last time I tried it a few months ago.

```
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python: started
    Running setup.py install for MySQL-python: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JjSDFe/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JjSDFe/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_GF1e3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-JjSDFe/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
     #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
      ^~~~~~~
    In file included from _mysql.c:46:
    /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:441:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
      if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                             ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JjSDFe/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JjSDFe/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_GF1e3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Could be related to this https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/176

Comment: This issue was fixed [in 2017](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/pull/177). If you want to use the MariaDB C API, you need to use version 1.3.11 or higher. Version 1.2.5 was released in 2014, is there any reason in particular you need a version *that* old?

Comment: @rickdenhaan when I update the version to 1.3.11 I get this error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python==1.3.11 (from versions: 1.2.3b1, 1.2.3b2, 1.2.3rc1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4b1, 1.2.4b2, 1.2.4b3, 1.2.4b4, 1.2.4b5, 1.2.4rc1, 1.2.4, 1.2.5)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. `MySQL-python` was abandoned a long time ago. I didn't notice you were using that package, the issue was fixed in the `mysqlclient` package which was originally a fork of `MySQL-python`. It should be a drop-in replacement.