# Python Docker build error when installing PIP packages

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am new to Python and trying to set up a docker environment and during the setup it installs all the required pip packages from a requirements.txt file.

I am currently getting this error before it stops

```
#8 161.2     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
#8 161.2     gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
#8 161.2     In file included from _mysql.c:29:
#8 161.2     /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
#8 161.2      #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
#8 161.2       ^~~~~~~
#8 161.2     In file included from _mysql.c:30:
#8 161.2     /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:444:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
#8 161.2        MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
#8 161.2        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 161.2     In file included from /usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
#8 161.2                      from _mysql.c:40:
#8 161.2     /usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1223: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
#8 161.2      #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#8 161.2
#8 161.2     In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:25,
#8 161.2                      from /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:38,
#8 161.2                      from _mysql.c:30:
#8 161.2     /usr/include/features.h:265: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#8 161.2      # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#8 161.2
#8 161.2     _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
#8 161.2     _mysql.c:1968:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
#8 161.2       if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
#8 161.2                                              ^
#8 161.2     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
#8 161.2     ----------------------------------------
#8 161.8 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6jeO4f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6jeO4f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-Cl1pr3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
#8 162.0 WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
#8 162.0 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I have tried installing GCC via homebrew etc but continuously running into the error above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you do what the message suggests: upgrade your pip version. That probably isn't the full cause of the error, but it might work; you never know! :-). Let me know if that works...

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a link to the only other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58124952/16775594) I found with the same error. Unfortunately, it's unanswered, but the information in the comments might help. It sounds like it's something to do with MySql. Could you provide `requirements.txt` in your question, or is it too large? Is there anything about Sql in there?

Comment: Hi. Please show us the version and the name of this library you're trying to install (this MySQL thing). As Sylvester said, the comments section inside the mentioned can be useful for you and probably your question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: The last comment in the mentioned question looks promising "MySQL-python was abandoned a long time ago. I didn't notice you were using that package, the issue was fixed in the mysqlclient package which was originally a fork of MySQL-python. It should be a drop-in replacement. – rickdenhaan Sep 26 '19 at 21:59". What package are you using?